# SQL + Return null record when no records meet the condition

Tags: mysql, left-join

Below is the structure of my table. I want to retrieve records even if the condition do not match. 
I have been using left join but the record is dropping since the condition do not match. Instead of dropping the record, I want to display a null value for tht column. 
As far as checked, left outer join is the way to go. I am doing the same but still not getting the desired output.

```
table 1 
Col1      Col2          Col3                  Col4
1           74          Desc 1          10/01/2015
2           85          Desc 2           09/01/2016
3           96          Desc 3           12/01/2015

table 2
Col4            Col5          Col6
AB               1            10/01/2015
CD               2            09/01/2016
EF               3            7/01/2015
GH               3            08/01/2015

Expected:
c1          dt                 exp   
1            10/01/2015         AB
2            09/01/2016         CD
3            12/01/2015

Getting:
c1          dt                  exp   
1            10/01/2015         AB
2            09/01/2016         CD


select tab1.col1 as c1, tab1.col4 as dt, tab2.col4 as exp
from tab1, tab 2
where tab1.col1 = tab2.col5
and tab1.col4 = tab2.col6(+)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Stop using the comma join syntax and use explicit inner/left/right join instead.

Comment: Yes it worked with explicit Left join. But using + or left join explicitly are both the same right? Do you know why it didn't work when using (+)?

Comment: Because when you put the condition in the where clause, it is effectively treated as an inner join. So, rows that do not satisfy the condition will not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your goal. But here is my guess:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8422d/2

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col5
AND t1.col4 = t2.col6
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a left join, in your example you can get the expected result with;

```
select *
from tab1 left join tab2
        on tab1.id = tab2.tab1_id and ...etc
```